# Не могу понять принцип работы данного выражения

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Проясните, пожалуйста, следующий момент.
У меня есть датафрейм в Pandas:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3],
                    'B': [2, 2, 7, 9, 10, 5, 3, 1, 8, 2]})
```

и я применяю `df1['A'].value_counts()` к столбцу A получаю следующее:

```
3    4
4    2
2    2
5    1
1    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Все понятно, но когда я применяю так: `df1['A'].value_counts()[df1['A']]`, то получаю следующее:

```
1    1
2    2
3    4
4    2
5    1
4    2
3    4
3    4
2    2
3    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Я понимаю, что произошло, но я не понимаю, как это сработало при добавлении к формуле `[df1['A']]`.
Можете пояснить на пальцах, почему датафрейм так вывелся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего страшного.

`df1['A'].value_counts()` - это серия.

Вы к ней применили `[df1['A']]`, что сокращенная запись для применения `.loc[df1['A']]`.

В квадратных скобках свойства `.loc` может быть для [документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) *список значений индекса* (или ему подобное) для получения соответствующих строк из серии.

Но вы его представили (в форме серии, которая в этом контексте рассматривается как список ее значений: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3]`), значит, вы получили из серии

```
df1['A'].value_counts()
```

строки с этими метками в индексе. Конечно, как серию.

---

*Примечание:*

Индексирование только квадратными скобками может быть для контекста интерпретировано по разному:

- строго по питонически (т.е. как применение метода `.__getitem__()`),
- как применение свойства `.loc[]` объекта типа DataFrame или Series,
- как применение свойства `.iloc[]` объекта типа DataFrame или Series.

К сожалению, контекст может быть иногда *многозначным* (но это не ваш случай) и тоже может быть в каких-то условиях *правильно определен только в ходе программы* (опять не ваш случай), что может иметь влияние на скорость (невозможно применить оптимизацию).

Потому [документация об индексации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) в синей рамке строго рекомендует (для последних двух случаев) использовать явную форму с применением `.loc` или `.iloc[]`.

Comment: Спасибо, честно говоря, я бы сам не догадался. А где можно посмотреть, что  [df1['A']] - это сокращенная запись для применения .loc[df1['A']]?

Comment: @Valeriy, я добавил это в мой ответ.

Comment: @Valeriy Antonov пометь ответ галочкой

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: К сожалению ссылка не работает "документация об индексации".

Comment: @Valeriy, исправил, проверил, спасибо за ваше сообщение.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @Valeriy, когда был мой ответ для вас полезным, вы можете голосовать за него (клик на треугольник вверх у его начала) и / или принять его (клик на галочку).

Comment: Добрый день. Я клик сделал, но с учётом того, что у меня ещё не набрался рейтинг 15, он не учитывается.

Comment: @Valeriy, спасибо, я об этом знаю. Но для клика на галочку не нужно никакого рейтинга, наоборот, это вам прибавит 2 баллы репутации. Конечно, решение это сделать зависит только от вас.

Comment: Вроде понял. Спасибо!